# Adding multiple markers on a google map in a visualforce component

Tags: visualforce-component, map, visualforce

I am creating a Visualforce component which holds a google map. The plan is to pass a list of addresses to this component and the map will place markers over these addresses.

Here is a sample visualforce component which shows markers for the hardcoded addresses :

```
<apex:component >

<apex:attribute name="addressList" type="String[]" description="array of addresses"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54, -2),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var addressArray = [];
    addressArray = '{!addressList}';

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
<style>
    #map {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      line-height:normal !important;
      height:500px;
      width: 800px;
      background:transparent;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div> 

</apex:component>
```

We can pass a List of addresses (as a List) to this component.

```
 <apex:page controller="MyCtrller">
    <c:MyMapComponent addressList="{!listOfAddresses}"/>
 </apex:page>
```

Where

```
  public class MyCtrller {
    public List<String> listOfAddresses {get; set;}

    public MyCtrller() {
       listOfAddresses = new List<String>();
       listOfAddresses.add('2001 Gemini St, Houston, TX');
       listOfAddresses.add('210 E Huron St, Ann Arbor');
       listOfAddress.add('45th Park Ave, New York');
    }
  }
```

However it gives me the following error:

```
   Geocode was not successful for the following reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

and

```
   Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS
```

Surprisingly if I hardcode the same addresses in the javascript like :

```
var addressArray = new Array("2001 Gemini St, Houston, TX" , "210 E Huron St, Ann Arbor", "45th Park Ave, New York");
```

it drops the markers on the respective locations.

I put an alert(addressArray) to check, but it seems addressArray is receiving the addresses correctly like this:

```
    [2001 Gemini St, Houston, TX, 210 E Huron St, Ann Arbor, 45th Park Ave, New York]
```

I do not understand how I am running out of query limits when I pass the addresses from a vf component. Or am I passing the addresses in an incorrect fashion?

Comment: Why have you hardcoded the addresses? for instance if we have 10 accounts then the addresses should be passed dynamically. Do you have any solution for that ?

Comment: The hardcoded address was just to show that the map code works. You can pass the addresses dynamically by querying them from the records.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out finally. The addressArray received a long string of addresses and so it was unable to determine the location for them. The work around is to user  in your javascript and push individual address in the addressArray.

Like this:

```
    var addressArray = new Array();
    <apex:repeat value="{!addressList}" var="address">
        addressArray.push("{!address}");
    </apex:repeat>
```

This will properly insert all the addresses in the array.

Note to reader: use google/firefox inspector more often for diagnosis.

Comment: Alternatively, you could `JSON.serialize()` the address list in the controller and put that in a property.

Answer (score 1):

The program need to be changed in two places

in controller

```
 public class MyCtrller {
    public List<String> listOfAddresses {get; set;}

    public MyCtrller() {
       listOfAddresses = new List<String>();
       listOfAddresses.add('\"2001 Gemini St, Houston, TX\"');
       listOfAddresses.add('\"210 E Huron St, Ann Arbor\"');
       listOfAddresses.add('\"45th Park Ave, New York\"');
    }
  }
```

Please note the double quotes has to be added in each  string

Now in component the variable declaration need to be changed as below

```
<apex:component >

<apex:attribute name="addressList" type="String[]" description="array of addresses"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54, -2),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   // var addressArray = [];  //  this line not required 
   // addressArray = '{!addressList}'; //this is invalid for creating array
    var addressArray = {!addressList};  // Use this format to fill addressArray 

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

});
</script>
<style>
    #map {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size:12px;
      line-height:normal !important;
      height:500px;
      width: 800px;
      background:transparent;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div> 

</apex:component>
```